# Debugging Lambda to EC2 Connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a simple Lambda deployed into my VPC that is making a call to an EC2 host in the same VPC (and subnet).  They both share an SG and I've used the Reachability Analyzer (from the Lambda ENI to the EC2 Instance) and it says they can talk.  But when I test the Lambda it sits on the HTTPS call (the call should be very quick) and eventually the Function timesout.

Any other ways to debug the Lambda->EC2 path, if that is even the issue.

Comment: How are you connecting from Lambda to EC2? Are you using private EC2 IP address to connect to it from the Lambda? If not, do you have NAT Gateway?

Comment: The security group needs to allow ingress traffic from itself (the SG). Do you have that configured?

Answer (score 0):

It usually sign that security group settings are blocking you.
Here is some steps for troubleshoot:

1. Your Security Group shouldn't block inbound or outbound connection to itself or EC2 and rather explicitly allowing it.
2. Check EC2 inbound rules, access to SG should be explicitly set there.

Comment: Subnets don't have to be the same. VPC Endpoint policies are not relevant.

Comment: Thanks for helping make response better

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply to everyone, but my issue was a 3rd party Firewall that was fronting the ALB. To test this theory I used the direct internal IP address of the server and it worked fine.